# Событие при нажатии на кливиши

Tags: javascript, jquery, клавиатура

Как на JS словить событие при нажатии на цифровые и клавиши ввода, но если сочетания этих клавиш, не учитывать.

Comment: Что за клавиши ввода?

Comment: Клавишы, где вводят буквы, цифры над буквами, вот это: https://msegceporticoprodassets.blob.core.windows.net/asset-blobs/11841_ru-ru_4

Comment: Какие сочетания???? 5 и 6? А и Б? Одновременно?

Comment: Нет. При нажтии на какие то из цифровых или буквенных клавиш, реагировать. А при например ctrl + c, ctrl + v, alt +tab, alt+esc и т.д., не реагировать

Comment: Надо проверять тогда нажата ли в это время другая клавиша. Держать эту клавишу в уме. Если нажата, то не принимаешь эти.

Comment: @Stas Для того, чтобы отслеживать нажатие 2 и более клавиш - необходимо прописывать это отдельно. Например, можно отслеживать данные нажатия кнопки или значения (Так как кнопка может быть `1`, или `!` при `shift+1`) По-этому необходимо отслеживать код кнопки.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```js
    window.onkeypress = (e) => { // При нажатии кнопки
        let key = e.key; // Получаем результат нажатия
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // от 1 до 9
            if (key == i && e.ctrlKey == false) { // Если код == цифре от 1 до 9 (Убирает нажатие шифта) И НЕ нажат ctrl, то...
                let z = document.getElementById('inp'); // получаем поле по id
                z.innerText += ' Нажата кнопка ' + key; // Записываем в него нажатое значение (Для демонстрации)
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<div id="inp"></div>
```